# Making animation based on COVID-19 data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, animation, cluster-analysis

There is an animation of the growth and spread of COVID-19 cases worldwide at http://www.healthmap.org/covid-19

My question is how do I make the same animation using Mathematica, also analyze the growth within specific territory like Melbourne.

(To be clear, I want to make a similar animation and related analysis with the data derived from the website or movie if it is possible.)

Here is the data used to make the movie:

https://github.com/beoutbreakprepared/nCoV2019/tree/master/latest_data

Answer (score 3):

[image]

There are many works to start from:

- [Propagation risk of COVID-19 by local contact in Spain](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1898126)
- [100 Days of COVID19 Over US Counties](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1956368)
- [Maps for Visualizing Covid-19's Effect](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1934457)

Also see works of **Hiroki Sayama**:

**CODE:** https://github.com/hsayama/COVID-19-geographical-animations

**VISUALS:**

- https://twitter.com/HirokiSayama/status/1261623727772631047
- https://twitter.com/HirokiSayama/status/1262109704328810496
- https://twitter.com/HirokiSayama/status/1301977095111929862

**GENERAL RESOURCES:** http://wolfr.am/coronavirus